# Where do I find electrical power transmission grid data?

Tags: power-supply, datasheet, power-engineering, distribution-network

I am looking for websites which provide datasheets of `3 phase electrical power transmission networks` with information about their `grid topology`. My aim is to first transform this data into following format:

```
topo = [[0,0.25,0.25,0.5,0],                             
        [0.25,0,0,0,0],                           
        [0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0],                
        [0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.01],            
        [0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0]]
```

introduce `power consumers` and `power generators` and use it for load flow calculations. This particular (theoretical) grid consists of `3 nodes` (1 to 3), `1 slack node` (4) and `1 fake slack node` (5, which is required in this case for specific reasons). The values in `topo` describe the `distances` between the `nodes` in the grid in `km`. It would be very handy, to have datasheets with similar `topology` information.

This is my first post in this stack, I am very sorry for potential flaws.

Comment: does this data need to be real, or are the IEEE test cases enough? I am not certain what you want to do with this data.

https://github.com/power-grid-lib/pglib-opf

IEEE test power systems can be found here

Comment: @Juan the IEEE test cases should suffice, though I was not able to find the data you mentioned. I will look into it. Thank you

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Andyaka Hardly a typical "shopping question". He's looking for information sources foir use as tools in order to perform engineering analysis. It's fdar from a "where do I get a widget that gnurls dibits" type query. The logical extension of this is to exsclude (yet another) set of queries that may be of use to others.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon well you're the moderator but, in my book (and I'm sure some others will agree) it's as much a shopping question as asking where to find this or that widget. It's also a question that solicits opinions in that if someone gave an answer it would be an opinion because there is no definitive answer.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm going to have to start saying what hat I'm wearing :-). That was a "fellow SE member opinion" hat comment.  I'm trying not to 'throw my officially available weight around' on matters which are as much an opinion among sort-of-peers (varies) as anything else.

Comment: When bears and rabbits decide to play peacefully, the rabbits never believe it LOL

Comment: @Andyaka I doubt that either of us quite qualify for either label (or we both qualify for both). You wouldn't have noticed (as things that don't happen tend not to be) that the term "BS" twice in a recent comment (re crystals) by you did NOT get edited to something like "misinformation" even though leaving it as was tended to violate the be nice policy wrt the newcomer on the receiving end of the comment. A little thing, no doubt, but I agonised over it, knowing how much you love having your input edited. I'm trying !!! :-) :-)

Comment: I think changing BS is something I wouldn't have a leg to stand on if I argued.